# Can I make my laptop work on full performance from battery?

Tags: power-management, hp, battery

I need my laptop to work wirelessly (without charger plugged in) with several devices attached via USB (Arduino, lidar, camera, etc.), but when I unplug charger it automatically  degrades performance.

I tried to install TLP and set TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC + TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=1, but it doesn't really help much. Is there any other tweaks I miss, or battery just can't handle that much power consumption?

Laptop is **HP Pavilion 4xx77ea#acb**.

Comment: Having all of those devices plugged in will probably drain your battery very quickly.

Comment: You may find something in your BIOS/UEFI (press [F10] at boot time) that will allow you to set the power profile while on battery, which overrides the OS. By default, most systems will reduce USB power and switch from the dedicated to on-chip graphics device. Some systems allow the OS to control this, but a lot of modern HP systems are designed for "consumers" rather than "people who know how to use a computer", hence all the "on selected models" disclaimers in their manuals 

Comment: @matigo, in UEFI I see only "Battery Remaining Time" option related to battery, it is not what I need unfortunately.